# Ruby code in yaml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a gem that have this e-mail method:

```
  #Sends and email for indicating a reply in an already created conversation
  def reply_message_email(message,receiver)
    @message = message
    @receiver = receiver
    subject = message.subject.to_s
    subject = strip_tags(subject) unless subject.html_safe?
    mail(:to => receiver.send(Mailboxer.email_method,message), :subject => t('mailboxer.message_mailer.subject_reply', :subject => subject)) do |format|
      format.text {render __method__}
      format.html {render __method__}
    end
  end
end
```

And I have this in my locale:

```
da:
  mailboxer:
    message_mailer:
        subject_reply: You have got a new reply "#{subject}"
```

Instead of overwriting the email method. Is it not possible to do some ruby code in a YAML file? Now the subject of an e-mail is just You have got a new reply "#{subject}" as text and the ruby code is not active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails' translation files don't permit Ruby, but they do have an interpolation mechanism. Try:

```
subject_reply: "You have got a new reply %{subject}"
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations for more details.